# SQL: Using CASE and returning only max value

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

Preemptive apology for any newbie omissions or obscurities in this question.

I have two tables that i want to join on a date.

```
Table1:
Closing Date
2013-04-26 00:00:00.000
2013-01-26 00:00:00.000

Table2:
Price Date
2013-04-24 00:00:00.000
2013-04-25 00:00:00.000
2013-04-26 00:00:00.000
2013-01-22 00:00:00.000
2013-01-23 00:00:00.000
2013-01-24 00:00:00.000
```

I want to pull ONLY the closest date (within the prior 5 days) from Table2 for each date in Table1, and then assign it either "MATCH" or "NONMATCH".

I have the following code

```
CASE Table2.PricingDate 
    WHEN Table1.[ClosingDate] THEN 'MATCH'
    WHEN DATEADD(D,-1, Table1.[ClosingDate]) THEN 'NONMATCH'
    WHEN DATEADD(D,-2, Table1.[ClosingDate]) THEN 'NONMATCH'
    WHEN DATEADD(D,-3, Table1.[ClosingDate]) THEN 'NONMATCH'
    WHEN DATEADD(D,-4, Table1.[ClosingDate]) THEN 'NONMATCH'
    WHEN DATEADD(D,-5, Table1.[ClosingDate]) THEN 'NONMATCH'
END [Match]

FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1
    ON Table2.PricingDate 
           BETWEEN DATEADD(D,-5,Table1.[ClosingDate]) AND Table1.[ClosingDate]

    WHERE
    CASE Table2.PricingDate 
        WHEN Table1.[ClosingDate] THEN 'MATCH'
        WHEN DATEADD(D,-1, Table1.[ClosingDate]) THEN 'NONMATCH'
        WHEN DATEADD(D,-2, Table1.[ClosingDate]) THEN 'NONMATCH'
        WHEN DATEADD(D,-3, Table1.[ClosingDate]) THEN 'NONMATCH'
        WHEN DATEADD(D,-4, Table1.[ClosingDate]) THEN 'NONMATCH'
        WHEN DATEADD(D,-5, Table1.[ClosingDate]) THEN 'NONMATCH'
    END  IS NOT NULL
```

The problem is that this returns more than one PricingDate for each ClosingDate:

```
**Closing Date            Price Date                Match**
2013-04-26 00:00:00.000   2013-04-24 00:00:00.000   NONMATCH
2013-04-26 00:00:00.000   2013-04-25 00:00:00.000   NONMATCH
2013-04-26 00:00:00.000   2013-04-26 00:00:00.000   MATCH
2013-01-26 00:00:00.000   2013-01-22 00:00:00.000   NONMATCH
2013-01-26 00:00:00.000   2013-01-23 00:00:00.000   NONMATCH
2013-01-26 00:00:00.000   2013-01-24 00:00:00.000   NONMATCH
```

And i want it only to return:

```
**Closing Date            Price Date                Match**
2013-04-26 00:00:00.000   2013-04-26 00:00:00.000   MATCH
2013-01-26 00:00:00.000   2013-01-24 00:00:00.000   NONMATCH
```

How can i get it to only return ONE pricingDate for each closingDate?
Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you're using SQL Server:

```
select
    T1.[Closing Date], T2.[Price Date],
    case
        when T1.[Closing Date] = T2.[Price Date] then 'MATCH'
        else 'NONMATCH'
    end as [Match]
from Table1 as T1
    outer apply (
        select top 1 T2.[Price Date]
        from Table2 as T2
        where
            T2.[Price Date] <= T1.[Closing Date] and
            T2.[Price Date] >= dateadd(day, -5, T1.[Closing Date])
            -- you can use between, I just like >= <= syntax more
            -- T2.[Price Date] between T1.[Closing Date] and dateadd(day, -5, T1.[Closing Date])
        order by T2.[Price Date] desc
    ) as T2
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2833/6)